# App publish error in Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have developed one application for  XXX company. In that I have used that company's logo and branding.

So, my app got rejected in play store review as **unauthorized use of copyrighted content.** 
What I did is ,I get the justification document from that company stating that **developer id**  & **package name** have the rights to access the branding and logo's. 
I have uploaded the same in google play advance note.

My Query is , there is no response from the team more than 14 hours. What I have to do. How can I proceed further. Whether can I upload the app again?. Kindly suggest me.????

Comment: My understanding is that it can be upwards of 48hrs before you get a response. After some googling I see where some people have waited 5 days.

Comment: I am sorry we can't help you, you just need to wait for their response.

Comment: What will happen if I upload the app again?

Comment: Only solution is **wait**. Got the response from the team.

Comment: Whether this problem will occur in future for the same package?.

Comment: What is latest status?

Answer (score 0):

Only Solution is to wait. Google play store will allow to upload or review team will ask for further information about the app to review.